# Get a list of all fields in a MongoDB Collection Using loopback

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I am using loopback. I have user table in mongodb.

I want unique column names(keys) of user table.

I have found below answer in mongodb.

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "my_collection",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
})

db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
["foo", "bar", "baz", "_id", ...]
```

But i am not sure how to do this in loopback.

Can anyone tell me how to implement above code in loopback.

Comment: Why would you need it in loopback? Why would you need this for any other purpose than analysis of your presently stored data? Not the sort of thing that is meant to be part of a production system.

Comment: could it be your question is how to filter your collection ?

Comment: @NeilLunn. I need it in loopback because i am using loopback. Purpose of this is my client need dynamic filters on user table. So he need unique column name. From that he  will decide Which column he want to display for his login dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the field filter in several ways, on your :

**REST API**

This is for one or more than one property.

`true` to include a field

`false` to exclude a field

```
?filter[fields][propertyName]=<true|false>&filter[fields][propertyName]=<true|false>...
```

for your case :

```
?filter[fields][names]=true&filter[fields][id]=false&filter[fields][something]=false
```

**NODE API**

```
model.find({ 
       fields: {
         propertyName: <true|false>, 
         propertyName: <true|false>,
          ... } 
    });
```

for your case :

```
 user.find({ 
           fields: {
             names: true, 
             something: false,
              ... } 
        });
```

[HERE the official documentation of the explanation above.](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Fields-filter.html)

**MODEL DEFINITION JSON**

You can use the scope property in your JSON model file (user.json) but this is not recommended because it will always find the names field only.

```
"scope": {
    { fields: {names: true, id: false, field: false} }
  },
```

[Check this official documentation for more information about SCOPES](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Model-definition-JSON-file.html)

**ANGULARJS Filter**

[this is the documentation for angularjs filters.](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/AngularJS-JavaScript-SDK.html)

Comment: Please read question carefully. It's not about filter on fields. It's about how to get unique field list from table.

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya sorry for missunderstanding, you mean you want a unique name list right ?

Comment: I need unique field(column) names like if collection has two records like `{fname:'..', lname: '...'}` &  `{fname:'..', lname: '...', company: '...'}` then i need result like `['fname', 'lname', 'company']`